# XML: How to get the value of a parent from the value of a grand-child in php

Tags: php, xml, xpath

I need to **get the account number of Company 3** in PHP...

Any and all help is appreciated...  I know that I need to create a variable from the code.  I think I may be able to us XPath, but I don't know how to do it.  Thanks

Here's my XML Response:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<GetAccountsWithAccessResponse>
    <Result>Success</Result>
    <Accounts>
        <Account>
            <AccountNumber>23871</AccountNumber>
            <Contact_id>10135</Contact_id>
            <IsOwner>N</IsOwner>
            <Groups>
                <Group>
                    <GroupID>12</GroupID>
                    <GroupName>Company 1</GroupName>
                    <GroupType>Private</GroupType>
                    <IncludeLoginLink>Yes</IncludeLoginLink>
                </Group>
                <Group>
                    <GroupID>28</GroupID>
                    <GroupName>Partners Group</GroupName>
                    <GroupType>Hidden</GroupType>
                    <IncludeLoginLink>No</IncludeLoginLink>
                </Group>
            </Groups>
        </Account>
        <Account>
            <AccountNumber>45160</AccountNumber>
            <Contact_id>0</Contact_id>
            <IsOwner>Y</IsOwner>
            <Groups>
                <Group>
                    <GroupID>1</GroupID>
                    <GroupName>Company 2</GroupName>
                    <GroupType>Private</GroupType>
                    <IncludeLoginLink>No</IncludeLoginLink>
                </Group>
                <Group>
                    <GroupID>2</GroupID>
                    <GroupName>Support</GroupName>
                    <GroupType>Private</GroupType>
                    <IncludeLoginLink>No</IncludeLoginLink>
                </Group>
            </Groups>
            <NumberOfContacts>10</NumberOfContacts>
            <MaximumContacts>2500</MaximumContacts>
        </Account>
        <Account>
            <AccountNumber>45166</AccountNumber>
            <Contact_id>6</Contact_id>
            <IsOwner>N</IsOwner>
            <Groups>
                <Group>
                    <GroupID>3</GroupID>
                    <GroupName>Company 3</GroupName>
                    <GroupType>Hidden</GroupType>
                    <IncludeLoginLink>No</IncludeLoginLink>
                </Group>
            </Groups>
            <NumberOfContacts>7569</NumberOfContacts>
            <MaximumContacts>10000</MaximumContacts>
        </Account>
    </Accounts>
</GetAccountsWithAccessResponse>
```

Any and all help is appreciated...  I know that I need to create a variable from the code.  I think I may be able to us XPath, but I don't know how to do it.  Thanks

Answer (score 0):

With XPath. you can specify...

```
//Account[Groups/Group/GroupName="Company 3"]/AccountNumber
```

This says to look for an AccountNumber element which has the GroupName with the value you want.

Using `[]` allows you to give a condition to select the element your after, but the result element is the element before the `[`.  So the result of this will be the Account element, and then the `/AccountNumber` at the end says select the AccountNumber element in the Account element.  Which gives...

```
<AccountNumber>45166</AccountNumber>
```

Comment: Thanks a million!!  This turned out very well for us.  Thanks again.

Answer (score 0):

PHPs DOM extension provides a `DOMXpath` class. With its `DOMXpath::evaluate()` you can fetch nodes and values.

```
$document = new DOMDocument();
$document->loadXML($xml);
$xpath = new DOMXpath($document);

var_dump($xpath->evaluate('string(//Account[Groups/Group/GroupName="Company 3"]/AccountNumber)'));
```

Output:

```
string(5) "45166"
```

#### Xpath expression

- any `Account` element node in the document...
  `//Account`
- ...that has an `Groups/Group/GroupName` with the value `Company 3`...
  `//Account[Groups/Group/GroupName="Company 3"]`
- ... its `AccountNumber` child element node...
  `//Account[Groups/Group/GroupName="Company 3"]/AccountNumber`
- ... as a string:
  `string(//Account[Groups/Group/GroupName="Company 3"]/AccountNumber)`

`string()` will return the text content of the first node in a list or an empty string if no node was found.

Answer (score 0):

Here is what I finally came up with:

```
$GroupName = "Company 3";

$xmlstr = <<<XML
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<GetAccountsWithAccessResponse>
    <Result>Success</Result>
    <Accounts>
        <Account>
            <AccountNumber>23871</AccountNumber>
            <Contact_id>10135</Contact_id>
            <IsOwner>N</IsOwner>
            <Groups>
                <Group>
                    <GroupID>12</GroupID>
                    <GroupName>Company 1</GroupName>
                    <GroupType>Private</GroupType>
                    <IncludeLoginLink>Yes</IncludeLoginLink>
                </Group>
                <Group>
                    <GroupID>28</GroupID>
                    <GroupName>Partners Group</GroupName>
                    <GroupType>Hidden</GroupType>
                    <IncludeLoginLink>No</IncludeLoginLink>
                </Group>
            </Groups>
        </Account>
        <Account>
            <AccountNumber>45160</AccountNumber>
            <Contact_id>0</Contact_id>
            <IsOwner>Y</IsOwner>
            <Groups>
                <Group>
                    <GroupID>1</GroupID>
                    <GroupName>Company 2</GroupName>
                    <GroupType>Private</GroupType>
                    <IncludeLoginLink>No</IncludeLoginLink>
                </Group>
                <Group>
                    <GroupID>2</GroupID>
                    <GroupName>Support</GroupName>
                    <GroupType>Private</GroupType>
                    <IncludeLoginLink>No</IncludeLoginLink>
                </Group>
            </Groups>
            <NumberOfContacts>10</NumberOfContacts>
            <MaximumContacts>2500</MaximumContacts>
        </Account>
        <Account>
            <AccountNumber>45166</AccountNumber>
            <Contact_id>6</Contact_id>
            <IsOwner>N</IsOwner>
            <Groups>
                <Group>
                    <GroupID>3</GroupID>
                    <GroupName>Company 3</GroupName>
                    <GroupType>Hidden</GroupType>
                    <IncludeLoginLink>No</IncludeLoginLink>
                </Group>
            </Groups>
            <NumberOfContacts>7569</NumberOfContacts>
            <MaximumContacts>10000</MaximumContacts>
        </Account>
    </Accounts>
</GetAccountsWithAccessResponse>
XML;

$xmlstring = new SimpleXMLElement($xmlstr);

//This Works for the GroupID:
$IDS = $xmlstring->xpath('//Group[GroupName="' . $GroupName . '"]/GroupID');
foreach($IDS as $theID) {
    $GroupID = $theID;
}

echo "The Group ID is $GroupID \n\n";

//This works for the Account Number
$acctnumbers = $xmlstring->xpath('//Account[Groups/Group/GroupName="' . $GroupName . '"]/AccountNumber');
    /* The following xpath also works:  $acctnumbers = $xmlstring->xpath('//Group[GroupName="' . $GroupName . '"]/parent::Groups/parent::Account/AccountNumber');  */

foreach($acctnumbers as $number) {
    $AccountNumber = $number;
}

echo "The account number is $AccountNumber";
```